# Argument dependant Name Lookup in C++ : point from n3290 Draft

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++11, name-lookup

A point from ISO C++ DRAFT n3290 :Argument dependant Name Lookup : section 3.4.2, para 2,

> For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero or more 
>    associated namespaces and a set of zero or more associated classes to be 
>    considered. The sets of namespaces and classes is determined entirely by the 
>    types of the function arguments (and the namespace of any template template 
>    argument).Typedef names and using-declaration s used to specify the types do 
>    not contribute to this set. The sets of namespaces and classes are determined
>    in the following way:
>
> — **If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespace and classes are
>      both empty.**
>
> — If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class
>      itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect
>      base classes. Its associated namespaces are the namespaces of which its 
>      associated classes are members.
>
> Furthermore, **if T is a class template 
>      specialization, its associated namespaces and classes also include: the 
>      namespaces and classes associated with the types of the template arguments 
>     provided for template type parameters (excluding template template parameters);
>     the namespaces of which any template template arguments are members; and the 
>     classes of which any member templates used as template template arguments are
>
>     members.**
>
> [ **Note:** Non-type template arguments do not contribute to the set of a
>      associated  namespaces. — end note ]

Can any one please expalin this in terms of an example ...please

here in the above statement "sets of namespaces and classes are both empty" ..how this is possible ?

And in the 2nd point he said the as further more ... please can any one explain this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental types, like `int` and `char`, are not defined in any namespace or class. That's why their list of associations will be empty.

If the function parameters are types created from a template, not only the namespace of this template is considered, but also the namespaces of its template parameters. For example if you have a `std::vector<foo::bar>` as a parameter, the set of namespaces will include both `std` and `foo`.